# subsetting dataframe depending on second dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two dataframes (df1 & df2) with the same dimensions. df1 contains numerical values:

```
df1
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81  91
2   2 12 22 32 42 52 62 72 82  92
3   3 13 23 33 43 53 63 73 83  93
4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
5   5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85  95
6   6 16 26 36 46 56 66 76 86  96
7   7 17 27 37 47 57 67 77 87  97
8   8 18 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

and df2 contains strings:

```
      V1        V2    V3        V4        V5             V6    V7        V8             V9            V10
1  today     today today     today yesterday          today today     today          today tomorrow,today
2  today     today today     today     today      yesterday today     today          today          today
3  today yesterday today     today     today          today today yesterday          today          today
4  today     today today     today     today          today today     today tomorrow,today          today
5  today     today today yesterday yesterday          today today     today          today       tomorrow
6  today     today today yesterday     today tomorrow,today today     today          today          today
7  today     today today     today     today      yesterday today     today          today tomorrow,today
8  today yesterday today     today     today          today today     today          today          today
9  today     today today     today     today          today today     today tomorrow,today          today
10 today yesterday today yesterday     today          today today yesterday          today          today
```

please note that some cells contain more than one string (e.g. [1,V10])

Each cell of df1 corresponds to a cell in df2 (df1[1,1] <-> df2[1,1], df1[2,2] <-> df2[2,2], etc.).

Is there a smart way (preferably without using a for-loop) to only keep values in df1, where the string from the corresponding cell in df2 contains "today" and the rest is set to NA?

So the prefered output would be:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1 11 21 31 NA 51 61 71 81  91
2   2 12 22 32 42 NA 62 72 82  92
3   3 NA 23 33 43 53 63 NA 83  93
4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
5   5 15 25 NA NA 55 65 75 85  NA
6   6 16 26 NA 46 56 66 76 86  96
7   7 17 27 37 47 NA 67 77 87  97
8   8 NA 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
10 10 NA 30 NA 50 60 70 NA 90 100
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
replace(df1, !sapply(df2, grepl, pattern = "today"), NA)
```

-output

```
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1 11 21 31 NA 51 61 71 81  91
2   2 12 22 32 42 NA 62 72 82  92
3   3 NA 23 33 43 53 63 NA 83  93
4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
5   5 15 25 NA NA 55 65 75 85  NA
6   6 16 26 NA 46 56 66 76 86  96
7   7 17 27 37 47 NA 67 77 87  97
8   8 NA 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
10 10 NA 30 NA 50 60 70 NA 90 100
```

---

Or slightly more compact

```
df1 * NA^!grepl("today", as.matrix(df2))
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1 11 21 31 NA 51 61 71 81  91
2   2 12 22 32 42 NA 62 72 82  92
3   3 NA 23 33 43 53 63 NA 83  93
4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
5   5 15 25 NA NA 55 65 75 85  NA
6   6 16 26 NA 46 56 66 76 86  96
7   7 17 27 37 47 NA 67 77 87  97
8   8 NA 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
10 10 NA 30 NA 50 60 70 NA 90 100
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = 11:20, V3 = 21:30, V4 = 31:40, 
    V5 = 41:50, V6 = 51:60, V7 = 61:70, V8 = 71:80, V9 = 81:90, 
    V10 = 91:100), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("today", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today"), V2 = c("today", 
"today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", "today", "yesterday", 
"today", "yesterday"), V3 = c("today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today"), V4 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "today", "yesterday", "yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "yesterday"), V5 = c("yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today"), V6 = c("today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", 
"tomorrow,today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today"), V7 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today"), V8 = c("today", "today", "yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "yesterday"), V9 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "tomorrow,today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "tomorrow,today", "today"), V10 = c("tomorrow,today", 
"today", "today", "today", "tomorrow", "today", "tomorrow,today", 
"today", "today", "today")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using a combination of `tidyverse` and base R:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1[!mutate(df2, across(everything(), ~ str_detect(.x, "today")))] <- NA
```

**Output**

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1 11 21 31 NA 51 61 71 81  91
2   2 12 22 32 42 NA 62 72 82  92
3   3 NA 23 33 43 53 63 NA 83  93
4   4 14 24 34 44 54 64 74 84  94
5   5 15 25 NA NA 55 65 75 85  NA
6   6 16 26 NA 46 56 66 76 86  96
7   7 17 27 37 47 NA 67 77 87  97
8   8 NA 28 38 48 58 68 78 88  98
9   9 19 29 39 49 59 69 79 89  99
10 10 NA 30 NA 50 60 70 NA 90 100
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = 11:20, V3 = 21:30, V4 = 31:40, 
    V5 = 41:50, V6 = 51:60, V7 = 61:70, V8 = 71:80, V9 = 81:90, 
    V10 = 91:100), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("today", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today"), V2 = c("today", 
"today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", "today", "yesterday", 
"today", "yesterday"), V3 = c("today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today"), V4 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "today", "yesterday", "yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "yesterday"), V5 = c("yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today"), V6 = c("today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today", 
"tomorrow,today", "yesterday", "today", "today", "today"), V7 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "today"), V8 = c("today", "today", "yesterday", "today", 
"today", "today", "today", "today", "today", "yesterday"), V9 = c("today", 
"today", "today", "tomorrow,today", "today", "today", "today", 
"today", "tomorrow,today", "today"), V10 = c("tomorrow,today", 
"today", "today", "today", "tomorrow", "today", "tomorrow,today", 
"today", "today", "today")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```